# Multiple elif with pass inside

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have several functions, all the functions do something and return either `True` or `False`. Then I have the following structure:

```
if function_1(myarg):
    pass
elif function_2(myarg):
    pass
elif function_3(myarg):
    pass
elif function_4(myarg):
    pass
elif function_5(myarg):
    pass
elif function_6(myarg):
    pass
else:
    do_something_else()
```

If a function returns `True`, then the code of the function has already been executed and I can pass the rest of the if-elif-else statement. Otherwise I test another function etc. until the `else` statement. Is this structure correct in Python? If it's correct but not 'pythonic', what is the more 'pythonic' way?

Comment: This statement is correct. You can read also about match-case statement in Python.

Comment: Why not loop over the functions, and `break` the loop when one returns true?

Comment: _Which_ statement is correct? How might one apply match-case?

Comment: Does "myarg" represent the same argument(s) for all functions?

Comment: Are you expecting to get all functions ran or just the first one that returns falsy?

Comment: @MichaelButscher Yes

Comment: @Sayse No just run the function that return `True`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably the most Pythonic way is containing your functions in a list and iterating through them with any() like so:

```
functions = [function_1, function_2, function_3]

if not any(func(myarg) for func in functions):
    do_something_else()
```

Comment: Does the order of the functions in the list matter ?

Comment: Yes, they will be executed in order they are defined in the list and after any of them returns True rest will not be executed. Just like in your original example. That's how any works with generator expressions.

Answer (score 2):

What you have certainly works, but will not be maintainable in the long term.

A more pythonic way would be to make a collection of the functions (assuming they all take the single argument `myarg`)

```py
functions = [function_1, function_2, function_3, function_4, function_5, function_6]
for f in functions:
    if f(myarg):
        break
else:
    do_something_else()
```